# Print multidimensional array to view file

Tags: arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, eloquent

Need help to represent array in view file. My code:

```
@foreach($standings as $team_name => $points)
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">#</th>
           <td>{{$team_name}}</td>
           <td>{{$points}}</td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

error msg:
*htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\laragon\www\fkbabrungas\resources\views\admin\leagues\standings.blade.php)*

array to print in view:

```
array:2 [▼
  "secondTeam" => & array:6 [▼
    "points" => 3
    "scoredGoals" => 3
    "goalsConceded" => 2
    "wins" => 1
    "loses" => 0
    "draws" => 0
  ]
  "firstTeam" => & array:6 [▶]
]
```

Comment: `expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` it is clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the syntax you're trying is incorrect try this you cannot print an array directly using laravel echo method

```
{{ implode(" ",$points); }}
```

if you want to access individual points inside the array you can use

```
{{$points['points']}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the $points variable is an array.

You need to access it like below

```
@foreach($standings as $team_name => $points)
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">#</th>
           <td>{{$team_name}}</td>
           <td>{{$points['points']}}</td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
           <td></td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Multi Dimensional Nested Array....

```
@foreach($standings as $team_name => $points)
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">#</th>
       <td>{{$team_name}}</td>
       <td>{{$points['points']}}</td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an array of single values, you have an array of arrays. Every element of this array is another array:

```
@foreach($standings as $team_name => $data)
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">#</th>
           <td>{{ $team_name }}</td>
           <td>{{ $data['points'] }}</td>
           <td>{{ $data['scoredGoals'] }}</td>
           <td>{{ $data['goalsConceded'] }}</td>
           <td>{{ $data['wins'] }}</td>
           <td>{{ $data['loses'] }}</td>
           <td>{{ $data['draws'] }}</td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```